# How to get my CSS working with webpack in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am trying to get my vue js to load my css file, but the app does not seem to recognize it. I also do not get any errors so trying to figure out where to even start has been difficult. Would anyone have any ideas of why this is not working? Below are my files and here is an image of my file tree - https://share.getcloudapp.com/KourXRmY

webpack.config.dev.js

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require('webpack')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
      './src/app.js'
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      watchOptions: {
        poll: true
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: [
            'vue-loader',
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            'vue-style-loader',
            'css-loader'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: true
      })
    ]
  }
```

app.js(main js file)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import '../assets/app.css';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and my css file

```
body {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}

.full-width {
width: 100%;
font-size: 500px;
}

.center-content {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: You need `style-loader`. `vue-style-loader` is only useful if the `style` is in a single file component. also, by loading your css in your javascript, you're going to get flashes of unstyled content. you should use an `isomorphic style loader` or use `minicssextractplugin` (in production) to ensure that the css actually gets rendered into a separate file and injected into the head.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thanks @Ohgodwhy and that is good to know for the other pieces of info you mentioned.